# problem centering logo as you resize screen

Tags: html, css

I am working on this website https://pure-cove-85477.herokuapp.com/
As you can see it has a logo in the middle that when you resize the screen it changes its size and position. I have tried to center it using media queries, positioning it differently as the screen size change, however, is not centered correctly in every device, especially if you use it on mobile with a landscape mode, the logo would stick out of the hero image.

I use https://www.responsinator.com/ to check that problem.

my question is, is there a simple DRY solution for this?

I tried using bootstrap columns but it was messier, media queries are the best solution I could think so far but it doesn't resolve the landscape view.

```
#hero img {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 25%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #hero img {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        max-width: 40%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        right: 30%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #hero img {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        max-width: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 23%;
        right: 35%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #hero img {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        max-width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        right: 40%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #hero img {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        max-width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        right: 40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you over-complicating this with absolute, top, right, etc.? Just use auto for left-right margins, the traditional solution; perhaps swap out, or reduce the size of, the image at smaller resolution. Probably the whole thing could be a covered background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this.

```css
#hero img {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gnprojects/image/upload/v1546601197/Website%20images/logo_la_tiendita_del_pan.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great ! this worked exactly as I wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you could try with display flex:

```css
#hero{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
img{
    max-width: 40%;
}
```

[image: landscape]